# onclick functionality for dynamically added images are not working properly

Tags: javascript, html, dom

i have added 5 stars to each table & added no of tables depending on array length. I wrote a click functionality to star image on which greystar_image changed to greenstar_image. when i clicked any star images in any row only starimages in 1st table is changing. what i need is, when i click a star in particular row,only starimage in that particular row should change.

my code is;

```
function init() {
        var Ques = ['a','b','c','d','e'];
        var container = document.getElementById('divStars');

        for(var i=0;i<Ques.length;i++){     
            var Table = document.createElement('table');
            Table.className = 'Table';
            var Row = document.createElement('tr');
            Row.className = 'Row';
            var Column = document.createElement('td');
            var x =document.createTextNode(Ques[i]);
            Column.appendChild(x);

            for(j=1;j<6;j++){   
                var starinput = document.createElement('input');
                starinput.type = 'image';
                starinput.id = j;
                starinput.class = 'imgclass';
                starinput.src="Images/greystar.png";
                Column.appendChild(starinput);
                starinput.onclick = function(){ 
                    ChangeState (this.id);
                    function ChangeState (index) { 
                        var colStars = divStars.getElementsByTagName ("input"); 
                        var k=0;
                        for(k=0;k <colStars.length;k++) { 
                            colStars [k]. src = (k <index? "Images/greenstar.png": "Images/greystar.png"); 
                        } 
                    }
                }
            }

            Row.appendChild(Column);
            Table.appendChild(Row);
            container.appendChild(Table);
        }
    }
    window.onload = init
</script></head>

<body><div id="divStars"> </div></body>
```

Comment: `divStars` is containing all the "starImages"? If so, you need to change `divStars` to `this.parentElement` in `ChangeState()` function.

Comment: @Teemu : it's still not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`divStars` contains all the `inputs` in your code, hence you are changing them all. You need to get `input`s in the parent element of the clicked `input` only, to change inputs in one row.  Something like this:

```
starinput.onclick = function(){ 
    ChangeState (this.id, this.parentElement);
    function ChangeState (index, parent) { 
        var colStars = parent.getElementsByTagName ("input");
                    ...
    }
}
```

[**A live demo at jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/yD4FX/).